# Error running ps1 from c# code (Office 365)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365

When creating the sharepoint site using ps1 file from C# code in office365. This error is coming
The 'connect-sposervice' command was found in the module 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell'.

Running the ps1 directly in powershell is giving the desired result, but not working properly using c# code

Comment: too little info. Show the C# code.

Comment: Please include the minimum examples of your PowerShell and C# code that reproduces this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solve it this way:

Locate file

*C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.psd1*

and change this line

```
# Processor architecture (None, X86, Amd64, IA64) required by this module
ProcessorArchitecture = 'Amd64'
```

for this one:

```
# Processor architecture (None, X86, Amd64, IA64) required by this module
ProcessorArchitecture = 'X86'
```

I don't know if it's a good solution, but it's works for me.
Any suggestion is wellcome