# Error running Powershell script from c#

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, office365

I have a ps1 script than runs fine when it is executed from powershell. It creates a user in Office365:

```
Param(
  [string]$adminUser,
  [string]$password,
  [string]$adminSite,
  [string]$userDisplayName,
  [string]$userFirstName,
  [string]$userLastName,
  [string]$userPrincipalName,
  [string]$userLicense,
  [string]$userOffice,
  [string]$userDepartment
)
try {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
    
    $executionPolicy = Get-ExecutionPolicy
    Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
    
    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($adminUser,$secpasswd)

    Connect-MSolService -Credential $credential
    #Write-Host "Conected to MSolService ..." -ForegroundColor Green 
    Connect-SPOService -Url $adminSite -Credential $credential # Here fail when running from .NET
    #Write-Host "Conected to SP Online ..." -ForegroundColor Green
    
    $user = New-MsolUser -FirstName $userFirstName -LastName $userLastName -UserPrincipalName $userPrincipalName -DisplayName $userDisplayName -LicenseAssignment $userLicenseAssignment -Office $userOffice -Department $userDepartment -UsageLocation ES
}catch [Exception] {
    #Write-host "An Exception ocurred. The proccess is uncompleted" -ForegroundColor Red
    #Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
    Set-ExecutionPolicy $executionPolicy
    return $false
}

Set-ExecutionPolicy $executionPolicy
    return $user
```

It works.
However, I have a C# program that executes this script in this way:

```
private Collection<PSObject> RunPsScriptFromFile(string psScriptPath, Dictionary<string, Object> parameters) {
  if (!File.Exists(psScriptPath)) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", psScriptPath);
  }

  Collection<PSObject> returnObjects = null;

  using (Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()) {
    runSpace.Open();
    RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runSpace);
    Pipeline pipeLine = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

    Command cmd = new Command(psScriptPath, false);
    if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0) {
      foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Object> p in parameters) {
        CommandParameter cp = new CommandParameter(p.Key, p.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(cp);
      }
    }

    pipeLine.Commands.Add(cmd);
    returnObjects = pipeLine.Invoke();
  }

  return returnObjects;
}
```

This program works fine with others scripts, but for this one, I get the following error (at the line I've marked in the script):

**The 'Connect-SPOService' command was found in the module 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell'.**

I found a question about this, but without answer:
[Error running ps1 from c# code (Office 365)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346107/error-running-ps1-from-c-sharp-code-office-365)

Comment: Did you run the command "Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell" in powershell? It should provide some information.

Comment: I did it. Anyway, I don't have any problem running the script in powershell, only from c# code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified my C# code:

```
pipeLine.Commands.Add(cmd);
returnObjects = pipeLine.Invoke();
var error = pipeLine.Error.ReadToEnd(); // New line
```

The "error" var contains the following:

**The current processor architecture is X86. The 'C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.psd1' module requires Amd64 architecture.**

I've located this file and I've changed this line

```
# Processor architecture (None, X86, Amd64, IA64) required by this module
ProcessorArchitecture = 'Amd64'
```

for this one:

```
# Processor architecture (None, X86, Amd64, IA64) required by this module
ProcessorArchitecture = 'X86'
```

I don't know if it's a good solution, but it's works. I will keep looking.
Any suggestion is wellcome.

Answer (score 0):

In `C:\Users\<your user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell`

There are two versions of powershell an x86 and a AMD64 helpfully with no suffix name.

Older versions of modules were written only in 32 bit, newer versions including the latest sharepoint online were written only in 64 bit.

If you start the environment in 32 bit it will obviously not run any 64 bit modules, and in a few edge cases you need to run the old 32 bit to run very old modules.

A better solution would be to invoke your powershell script
`%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "script.ps1"`

I would guess your finding the syswow 32 bit version first.